# Django-nonrel in Google App Engine ListField

Tags: google-app-engine, listfield, django-nonrel

I am trying to build an example app in Google App Engine using django-nonrel. and am having problems implementing ListField attribute into a model.

I have created an app **test_model** and have included it as an installed app in my settings. The model.py is:

> ```
> from django.db import models
> from djangotoolbox import *
> from dbindexer import *
>
> # Create your models here.
> class Example(models.Model):
>     some_choices = models.ListField('Choice_examples')
>     notes = models.CharField(max_length='20')
>     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
>
>     def __unicode__(self):
>         return u'%s' % (self.notes)
>
>
> class Choice_examples(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length='30')
>
>     def __unicode__(self):
>         return u'%s' % (self.name)
> ```

The above example gives me:
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'Model'

If I comment out the djangotoolbox import, I get the following :
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ListField'

What am I doing wrong here? I can't seem to find any documention as to how to go about using ListField in django-nonrel. Is that because it is supposed to really obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is that you cannot pass an object into fields.ListField.

I have ditched trying to work with ListField as documentation is limited and my coding skills aren't at a level for me to work it out.

Anyone else coming across a similar problem, you should consider create a new model to map the ManyToMany relationships. And if the admin view is important, you should look into the following to display the ManyToMany table inline with any given admin view:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#s-working-with-many-to-many-models

Answer (score 4):

Your imports are smashing each other:

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox import *
```

The second import will replace the django.db models with djangotoolbox' empty models module. Using `from X import *` is a terrible idea in general in Python and produces confusing results like these.

If you're looking to use ListField from djangotoolbox, use:

```
from djangotoolbox import fields
```

and refer to the ListField class as `fields.ListField`.

Comment: Thanks Greensnark. I think I'm nearly there with it. Now getting the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: Exception location is: fields.py in contribute_to_class, line 13

Answer (score 3):

OK, here is what I did to be able to use ListFields. `MyClass` the equivalent to your `Example` class and `AnotherClass` is the same as your `Choice_examples`. What I describe will allow you to use `ListField`s in the admin interface and your self implemented views.

I'll start from the beginning

This is what what my model looks like

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    field = ListField(models.ForeignKey(AnotherClass))
```

I wanted to be able to use the admin interface to create/edit instances of this model using a multiple select widget for the list field. Therefore, I created some custom classes as follows

```
class ModelListField(ListField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return FormListField(**kwargs)

class ListFieldWidget(SelectMultiple):
    pass

class FormListField(MultipleChoiceField):
    """
    This is a custom form field that can display a ModelListField as a Multiple Select GUI element.
    """
    widget = ListFieldWidget

    def clean(self, value):
        #TODO: clean your data in whatever way is correct in your case and return cleaned data instead of just the value
        return value
```

These classes allow the listfield to be used in the admin. Then I created a form to use in the admin site

```
class MyClassForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClasstForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field'].widget.choices = [(i.pk, i) for i in AnotherClass.objects.all()]
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['field'].initial = self.instance.field

    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
```

After having done this I created a admin model and registered it with the admin site

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyClassForm

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super(MyClassAdmin,self).__init__(model, admin_site)

admin.site.register(MyClass, MyClassAdmin)
```

This is now working in my code. Keep in mind that this approach might not at all be well suited for google_appengine as I am not very adept at how it works and it might create inefficient queries an such.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but try with:

```
class Choice_examples(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='30')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Example(models.Model):
    some_choices = models.ListField(Choice_examples)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length='20')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.notes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sahid, I tried the changes which are I gathered, 1) the reorder the classes 2) Remove the single quotes from Choice_examples. Unfortunately these changes didn't fix it.